# Filter data based on dropdown selection in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a a JSON file with a list of data sorted by language/country. This data is being displayed in a standard HTML table. But because the table will get too long, I would like to be able to have a dropdown with the list of countries and filter the results of the table based on this selection.

```
[
    { "language": "English (United States)", "name": "New York" },
    { "language": "English (United States)", "name": "Chicago" },
    { "language": "English (United Kingdom)", "name": "London" },
    { "language": "English (United Kingdom)", "name": "Manchester" },
    { "language": "English (Australia)", "name": "Melbourne" },
    { "language": "English (Australia)", "name": "Sydney" }
]
```

This is the vue file.

```
<script>
  import countries from 'countries.json'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
         countries: countries,
         filter: ''
       }
    }

  }
</script>

<template>
  <select name="filter" id="langFilter" v-model="filter">
    <option value="English (United States)">English (United States)</option>
    <option value="English (United Kingdom)">English (United Kingdom)</option>
    <option value="English (Australia)">English (Australia)</option>
  </select>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-nowrap align-middle mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Language</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(country, index) in countries" :key="index">
          <td>{{ country.language }}</td>
          <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 ways you can do it. You can use v-if to show only rows that match your filter.

```
<template v-for="(country, index) in countries" :key="index">
    <tr v-if="country.language === filter">
        <td>{{ country.language }}</td>
        <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Or alternatively, you can use a computed value.

When the filter changes, the `filteredCountries` computed value will return only the countries that match the filter.

I have provided a working code based on what you gave.

```
<script>
  import countries from './countries.json'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
         countries: countries,
         filter: ''
       }
    },
    computed: {
      filteredCountries() {
        return this.countries.filter((country) => {
          return country.language === this.filter;
        })
      }
    }

  }
</script>

<template>
  <select name="filter" id="langFilter" v-model="filter">
    <option value="English (United States)">English (United States)</option>
    <option value="English (United Kingdom)">English (United Kingdom)</option>
    <option value="English (Australia)">English (Australia)</option>
  </select>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-nowrap align-middle mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Language</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(country, index) in filteredCountries" :key="index">
            <td>{{ country.language }}</td>
            <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, no one know `<datalist>`?

```html
<script>
  import countries from 'countries.json'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
         countries: countries,
         filter: ''
       }
    }

  }
</script>

<template>
  <input list="langFilter" v-model="filter">

  <datalist id="langFilter">
    <!-- All you need to do is to for loop your countries array -->
    <option value="English (United States)">English (United States)</option>
    <option value="English (United Kingdom)">English (United Kingdom)</option>
    <option value="English (Australia)">English (Australia)</option>
    <option value="Italian (Italy)">Italian (Italy)</option>
  </datalist>
</template>
```

**A proof it's work!**

```html
<input list="langFilter" v-model="filter">

<datalist id="langFilter">
<!-- All you need to do is to for loop your countries array -->
<option value="English (United States)">English (United States)</option>
<option value="English (United Kingdom)">English (United Kingdom)</option>
<option value="English (Australia)">English (Australia)</option>
<option value="Italian (Italy)">Italian (Italy)</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: This doesn't work and to be honest, `select` is a much better choice UI wise.

Comment: @Halnex To be honest, it not work for you. I added an extra field with Italian language, try now filter Italian language. When you start typing, English fields will disappear.

Comment: @Halnex If you try to filter an array where all fields start with `English` and you type `English` no wonder it looks like not working.

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing the selection model value in the `filter` variable. You can simply filtered out the `countries` array in the template itself inside `v-for`.

```
<tr v-for="(country, index) in countries.filter(c => c.language === filter)" :key="index">
    <td>{{ country.language }}</td>
    <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
</tr>
```